# how to auto integrate to branch with svn command

Tags: bash, shell, svn, command, branch

Is there a command or shell-tool to auto-integrate a commit to branch?

I can go around it by

```
svn diff . -rCOMMIT (or similar) > ../diff.diff 
cd ../branches/MyBranch 
patch -p0 -i ../../diff.diff
rm ../../diff.diff
cd -
```

or even fit it in one line separated by ';' and then

```
svn ci -m 'a tiresome way around it'
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for cherry-picking.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking

```
svn merge -c rev ^/branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Subversion performs reintegrate merges automatically starting with version 1.8. Read [SVNBook 1.8 | Reintegrating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate).